# Dependency on mock method with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm attempting to write PHPUnit tests for an Email abstraction class i'm using. The class interacts with the Mailgun API but I don't want to touch this in my test, I just want to return the response I would expect from Mailgun.

Within my test I have a setup method:

```
class EmailTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    private $emailService;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $mailgun = $this->getMockBuilder('SlmMail\Service\MailgunService')
                        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                        ->getMock();

        $mailgun->method('send')
                ->willReturn('<2342423@sandbox54533434.mailgun.org>');

        $this->emailService = new Email($mailgun);
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testEmailServiceCanSend()
    {
        $output = $this->emailService->send("me@test.com");
        var_dump($output);
    }
}
```

This is the basic outline of the email class

```
use Zend\Http\Exception\RuntimeException as ZendRuntimeException;
use Zend\Mail\Message;
use SlmMail\Service\MailgunService;


class Email
{

    public function __construct($service = MailgunService::class){
        $config    = ['domain' => $this->domain, 'key' => $this->key];
        $this->service = new $service($config['domain'], $config['key']);
    }

    public function send($to){
        $message = new Message;
        $message->setTo($to);
        $message->setSubject("test subject");
        $message->setFrom($this->fromAddress);
        $message->setBody("test content");

        try {
            $result = $this->service->send($message);
            return $result;
        } catch(ZendRuntimeException $e) {
            /**
             * HTTP exception - (probably) triggered by network connectivity issue with Mailgun
             */
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

`var_dump($output);` is currently outputting `NULL` rather than the string i'm expecting. The method `send` i'm stubbing in the mock object has a dependency through an argument, and when I call `$mailgun->send()` directly it errors based on this so I wonder if this is what is failing behind the scenes. Is there a way to pass this argument in, or should I approach this a different way?

Comment: You probably need to include code for `Email::send`, as it seems the problem lies here. The test looks ok. If `Email::send` is a simple proxy like `return $this->mailgun->send();` your `$output` should contain the canned response.

Comment: added the basic email class to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange it does not throw an exception in `Email::__construct`.
The expected parameter is a **string**, and the `MailgunService` object is instantiated within the email constructor. In your test you are passing the **object**, so I would expect and error at line

```
$this->service = new $service($config['domain'], $config['key']);
```

What you need is:

```
class Email
{
    public function __construct($service = null){
        $config    = ['domain' => $this->domain, 'key' => $this->key];
        $this->service = $service?: new MailgunService($config['domain'], $config['key']);
    }
```

Also, it may not be a good idea to catch an exception and return nothing in `Email::send`.

Comment: good spot! yes, i'm unsure why that wasn't throwing an error already. The exception handling in email::send was just a snippet btw, it is handled.